# Distrobox: emacs: Could not open file: /dev/tty

Tags: docker, emacs, container, emulation

Am currently trying to automate running `emacs` on a Distrobox container (the Docker container is `silex/emacs:29.2-alpine`, although I've also tried `silex/emacs:29.2` which uses a Debian image), and am getting the error `emacs: Could not open file: /dev/tty`. Here's what I'm doing:

```
distrobox create --name test --image silex/emacs:29.2-alpine --home /home/dbhome
distrobox enter test -nw -- /nix/store/emacs/bin/emacs-29.2
```

Which produces the mentioned error. However, running first `distrobox enter test -nw`, and then running `/nix/store/emacs/bin/emacs-29.2` does successfully start `emacs` within the distrobox container. The issue is, I want to automate this emacs startup, so I need to find a way that would allow me to startup the emacs from the container from a sequence of commands ran outside the container.

Anyone know what my be causing `emacs: Could not open file: /dev/tty` in this way? The reason I'm using Distrobox instead of just a regular container is that I eventually want to use Distrobox's ootb support for connecting to the host's X11 sockets.

EDIT: `strace` confirms the error is `-1 ENXIO (No such device or address)`

EDIT2: The problem subsides if we replace a bit of the `docker exec` command ran by `distrobox enter`. The `docker exec` command ends with `CONTAINERNAME su USERNAME -c COMMAND`; the issue gets fixed when we use `CONTAINERNAME COMMAND` directly.

Comment: PS: `/nix/store/emacs/bin/emacs-29.2` is used to run emacs in this container because it is build in two stages beginning from a nix base before using alpine. The Dockerfile is accessible at https://github.com/Silex/docker-emacs/blob/master/29.2/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: Are you trying to start an interactive emacs with a X11 gui or are you trying to send emacs some kind of automated text input?